# Display in stock products list with Custom Listing extension in Magento 1.7

Tags: php, magento

I'm using "Custom listing" extension ( github.com/openstream/CustomListing/ ) which allow to create CMS pages like all specials price products list, best sellers products list, and much more.

But it can't do what I need to do.
I need to list all in stock products. Here is my php request :

```
if (is_null($this->_productCollection)) {
        $this->_productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection');
        $this->_productCollection->joinField('inventory_in_stock', 'cataloginventory_stock_item', 'is_in_stock', 'product_id=entity_id','is_in_stock>=1', 'left')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
            ->addStoreFilter();
    }
    return $this->_productCollection;
```

This request works, but the result is wrong.
It displays all the products, all in stock and all out of stock products.
Does anybody know what is wrong in my request ? 
Thanks for your help !
My magento version is : Community Edition 1.7.0.2

Answer (score 0):

The following code snippet will return you the products of a category that have status 'Enable' , Visibility 'catalog,search' and Stock Availability ' In stock'.

```
$productDetails = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($cat_id)
                  ->getProductCollection()
                  ->addAttributeToSelect('*');

$productDetails->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', array('in' => array(4) )); 
$productDetails->addAttributeToFilter('status', array('in' => array(1) )); 
$productDetails->joinField('is_in_stock',
                            'cataloginventory/stock_item',
                            'is_in_stock',
                            'product_id=entity_id',
                            'is_in_stock=1',
                            '{{table}}.stock_id=1',
                            'left');
```